# Simulator not installed

Tags: xcode, react-native, npm, ios-simulator, expo

So i got this new mac and i have been trying to run expo start(Run on ios) but keep getting this error and i have xcode installed on my mac

> Simulator not installed. Please visit https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ to download Xcode and the iOS simulator. If you already have the latest version of Xcode installed, you may have to run the command `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`.

What actually solved it for me was simply making sure i have xcode in Applications folder.
Just thought this might help someone out there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for posting! I had the same issue and resolved it by:

1. Verifying Xcode was in my Applications folder
2. From the root folder I ran the command `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`
3. After that, with expo running, I typed in `i` and was all set with the iOS Simulator.

Thanks for posting!